# How to print a method returning an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a method converting a 2D array into a 1D array but I'm having troubling printing it. There's a problem with making a new array in the main method or calling the method. anyone can help??

```
public class flatten {

public static int[] flatten1(int[][] a){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
            c++;
        }   
    }

    int[] x = new int[c];
    int k=0;

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
            x[k++]=a[i][j];
        }
}
    return x;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
    flatten1 f = new flatten1({{2,5,3,7,4,8},{3,4,1,2}});
    for(int i=0; i<f.length;i++){

        System.out.print(f[i]+" ");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot do this:

```
   flatten1 f = new flatten1({{2,5,3,7,4,8},{3,4,1,2}});
```

flatten1 is not a class it is a method, you cannot instantiate flatten1 and input a 2D int array.
For the above to legal, you would need to create a class called flatten1 and create a constructor which takes a 2D int array as a parameter and I believe that is not what you want to do.

---

Your flatten method works perfectly fine, change your main method to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   int[][] arrayToBeFlattened = {{2,5,3,7,4,8},{3,4,1,2}};
   int[] oneD = flatten1(arrayToBeFlattened);

   for(int i=0; i<oneD.length;i++){
      System.out.print(oneD[i]+" ");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class flatten {

    public static int[] flatten1(int[][] a) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                c++;
            }
        }

        int[] x = new int[c];
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                x[k++] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] test_arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

        int[] f = flatten.flatten1(test_arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(f[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, when you print f[i] you're not printing the first value. Since f is an array of arrays you're trying to print the ith array not the i'th *element*. Make sure you understand this distinction because it's important. Printing the ith array will simply give you its memory address.

To fix this, simply change your print statement to:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(f[i])+" ");
```